# Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n/2\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. When does ${\cal N}(AB)\cap {\cal N}(A)=\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, real-numbers, matrix-rank

Assume $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n/2\times n}$ with rank $n/2$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with rank $n$. Under what conditions can I claim that ${\cal N}(AB)\cap {\cal N}(A)=\{0\}$, where ${\cal N}(\cdot)$ stands for nullspace?

Also, under what conditions can I claim ${\cal N}(AB^m)\cap {\cal N}(A)=\{0\}$ where $m$ is a positive integer number.

Obviously, $B$ cannot be the identity matrix for the first case or an involutory matrix for the latter.

Comment: For your second question, do you mean for a particular $m$, or for all $m>0$ at once?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I meant for all $m>0$, not a particular one. I am trying to figure out if I can extrapolate the result from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_{\tfrac{n}{2}})$ be a basis for $\mathcal{N}(A)$, and extend this to a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathcal{N}(AB)\cap\mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$ if and only if $B$ maps each of $e_1,\ldots,e_{\tfrac{n}{2}}$ outside $\mathcal{N}(A)$. This is the case if and only if the first $\tfrac{n}{2}$ columns of $B$ (with respect to this basis!) are not in $\mathcal{N}(A)$.

An example of a matrix $B$ for which $\mathcal{N}(AB^m)\cap\mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$ holds for all positive integers $m$ is
$$B=I_n+\begin{pmatrix}0&I_{\tfrac{n}{2}}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Also note that, because $B$ is of full rank, we have $\mathcal{N}(AB)=B^{-1}\mathcal{N}(A)$. So you want 
$$B^{-1}\mathcal{N}(A)\cap\mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}.$$

Comment: I will appreciate if you can elaborate on something... 

You mentioned that ${\cal N}(AB)\cap {\cal N}(A)=\{0\}$  if and only if the first $n/2$ columns of $B$ are not in the ${\cal N}(A)$. Where does that come from? Let say that $$A = [1~0]$$ and $$ B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ The first column of $B$ is not in the nullspace of $A$ yet $A$ and $AB$ have the same nullspace. We can note that the last column of $B$ is in the nullspace of $A$. Thanks for the last answer/tip, I will try to see how can I use it!!! I also can tell that triangular matrix could be OK.

Comment: Very sharp! This statement holds with respect to certain bases, as described in the question: Bases for which the first $\tfrac{n}{2}$ basis vectors span $\mathcal{N}(A)$. This means the first $\tfrac{n}{2}$ columns of $A$ are all zero with respect to this basis. So we shouldn't expect this to be true for $A=[1\ 0]$ , but it should be true for $A=[0\ 1]$.